# How to remove from a list in python, all but one of the elements that have equal length?

Tags: python, string, list, string-length

I am inputting a list and it must contain only one element of a particular length.

I tried:

```
lst = list(input("list: "))
for i, j in lst:
    if len(j) == len(i):
        lst.remove(j)
print(lst)
```

It's showing this:

```
for i, j in lst:
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

And I don't know what this error means, where am I going wrong? Can you please suggest something?

Comment: You cannot iterate over a list like that, here's how you can do that:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/74783791/15923186
The error basically says, that when using `for` loop a single element is given in each iteration and you are expecting two of them at the same time. `for` loop in python iterates through the objects in the list and NOT their indices,,,

Comment: What do you enter as input and what do you expect to be the resulting values of `i` and `j`?

Comment: Have you considered reading: https://www.python.org/about/gettingstarted/

Answer (score 0):

Edit: You cannot use `len()`. How will you know  if genip or pears? Both are  containing 5 characters.

Easier way to do this:

```
fruits = ["apples", "bananas", 'genip', "pears", "mango", 'coconut']
lst = input()
res = [i for i in fruits if i not in lst]
print(f'List after removing duplicate elements: {res}')
```

Result type: genip # to remove it.

List after removing duplicate elements: ['apples', 'bananas', 'pears', 'mango', 'coconut']